# Multiple Symfony-DoctrineGuardPlugins in one Database?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I wrote a Symfony 1.4 (Doctrine) Website consisting of 2 frontends and 2 backends. So all is neatly packed in 2 SF-Projects - anyways all the apps use the same (MySQL-)database. This is not a problem at all until it comes to the point of logging in different users.

Backend 1 can only be accessed from the intra-net, so here's just a few users (admins) to manage. Backend 2 can be accessed from the extra-net and should manage the frontend-users, too.

Basically I want to split this two Projects in 2 different sets of user-tables - but within one Database.

I use the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin to secure the first app and I'm not sure how to manage securing the second one without interfering the 1st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you add a field `app_type` (intranet, extranet) in your user table, and modify your registering and login processes using this field, so that you easily have 2 lists of users on 1 table ?